# Topic with "Example" in its name

Tags: discussion, documentation

Just want to clear this moment: is it normal to create the topic with the name "Example *of something*"? Shouldn't name be something like "Introduction/Usage *of something*" with examples in according section inside this topic?

I already [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wpf/topic-requests/1199#commentId=2296) this question in comment of one topic request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would agree that 'example' is not correct for a topic title. As is stated in the [Documentation tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation):

> Documentation for a tag - .net, say - is composed of topics which are groups of related examples, accompanied by optional prose. Things like "Arrays," "Extension Methods," "Maps," and "Higher Kinded Types".

So topics should be groups of related examples, not an example itself.

===============================================

Specific to this topic/example:

- Topic name: MVVM (or spelled out)
- Example name: MVVM example

  - The Model (**M**VVM)
  - The View (M**V**VM)
  - The View-Model (MV**VM**)

So an example of MVVM, where each of the 3 steps is part of that single example.

Comment: So true, but if topic is already exists (created from proposal), and topic content is good enough, how to tell people to change title? Make it with improvement request?

Comment: @Sam, I have edited my question as to how I look at it. How to change this if we think it can/should be improved, is a nice other question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait for a while if anyone else have some opinions. Please edit all MVVN to MVV*M*.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Note to self: never copy-paste...